# $\sum \frac{x}{n^{a}(1+nx^{2})}$ converge uniformly in $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Let $a>1/2.$ Determine if a series converge uniformly in $\mathbb{R}:$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{n^{a}(1+nx^{2})}$$

If $x>0$  ... it is easy to prove that

$$\left |\frac{x}{n^{a}(1+nx^{2})}  \right |\leq \frac{1}{2n^{a+\frac{1}{2}}}  $$

is then only apply (Test- Weiersstras )... However, if $x < 0$ have difficulties. Some help?

Comment: This is an actual question and not a hint, but can't you just consider the convergence of  $-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{n^{a}(1+nx^{2})}$ when $x < 0$?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but doesn't the same method work for $x<0$?

Comment: I think the same method will work for $x<0$ also.

Comment: Oh well, editing your question does outdate a bit the content of the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** *after the OP's edit, only the second point remains relevant.*

- You should find an upper bound of $$
  \frac{1}{2n^{a+\frac{1}{2}}}
  $$
  not $\frac{1}{2n^{a+1}}$. *(Which makes "sense", given the assumption. Otherwise, why bother with $a>\frac{1}{2}$ specifically?)* Namely, you want to find the maximum of $f\colon [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = \frac{x}{1+nx^2}$, and this maximum occurs at $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.
- The LHS you are trying to upper bound is even (in $x$), so the argument automatically applies to $x< 0$ as well.